# Нарисовать ромб из цифр в Python

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать ромб из цифр на Python, уже несколько дней пытаюсь. Должно получаться примерно так:

```
   1
  121
 12321
  121
   1
```

Вот мой недоромб, не могу понять, как дописать его правую нижнюю часть:

```
n = int(input()) 
x = ""
for i in range(1, n + 1): 
    x = x + str(i)
    print(' '*(n-i) + x + x[-2::-1])
    
for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):
    print(' '*(n-i), sep='', end='')
    for k in range(1, i + 1):
        print(k, end='')
    print()
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: что должно на вход подаваться? n определно в задании?

Comment: n не определено в задании, вводится при выполнении программы, от n зависит размер ромба

Comment: Это то понятно. Что значит n? максимальное значение, которое есть в ромбе или количество строк?

Comment: n - максимальное значение. Количество строк= n*2-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если все таки "Улитка"

```
    x= int(input())
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
      print(' '*(x-i), end='')
      for j in range(1, i+1):
        print(j, end = '')
      for j in range(i-1, 0,-1):
        print(j, end = '')
      print()
    for z in range(x-1, 0, -1):
      print(' '*(x-z), end='')
      for k in range(1, z + 1):
        print(k, end='')
      for k in range (z-1,0,-1):
        print (k, end='')
      print()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Самый простой вариант для меня)

Answer (score 10):

Не разбирая по четвертям - это не "улитка", которая зависит от сектора. Тут главное придумать формулу для элемента.

```
n = 4
w = n*2-1
ar  = [ ]

for y in range(w):
   ar.append([])
   for x in range(w):
       d = n - abs(x+1-n) - abs(y+1-n)
       ar[y].append( d if d > 0 else " ")

for l in ar:
    print(*l,sep='')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def get_list(n):
    return list(range(1, n+1)) + list(range(n-1,0,-1)) # Рисует строку так, как нам нужно

inp = int(input())
height = get_list(inp) # Центральный вертикальный столбец
width = inp*2-1 # Ширина центральной строки. Она берётся как максимальная ширина всего ромба


for step in height: # Идём сверху вниз по вертикальному столбцу
    strs = (str(x) for x in get_list(step)) # И генерируем горизонтальные
    level = ''.join(strs)
    print(level.center(width)) # Правильно выводим строки с учётом максимальной ширины
```

Comment: На будущее. Не злоупотребляйте таким количеством преобразований в одной строке. Лучше распихать это все по переменным - человеку так понятнее будет

Comment: @Shift на самом деле я с вами полностью согласен. Просто писал ночью, как-то было не до того

Comment: Хорошо, прекрасно понимаю. Хотел внести правки в ответ, но, аналогично не до этого.

Comment: Я сам поправлю, если время будет

Comment: зачем width л строке преобразовывать?  кстати `n*2-1`

Comment: strs к листу тоже не надо - для жоина генератор пойдет

Comment: @eri я пробовал и `n*2-1` и `n*2` и разницы никакой не нашёл

Comment: ну это изза округления 0,5 до 1 при выравнивании через ^)

Comment: зачем столько преобразований к листу?)

Comment: Я так-то это понимаю, но разницы действительно не увидел.

Comment: `list(range(1, n+1)) + list(range(n-1,0,-1))`

Comment: вцелом замудренный ответ, но мне нравится, плюсик поставил

Comment: @eri Вроде бы немного размудрил

Answer (score 1):

На первом этапе мы рисуем верхнюю часть ромба, получая ее путем склеивания двух переменных для левой и правой части.
На втором этапе от этих переменных и отсекаем по одному символу и продолжаем их склеивать.

```
ch = 9
sumLeft = ""
sumRight = ""
for i in range(1,ch+1): 
  sumLeft+=str(i)
  print ((" "*(ch-i))+sumLeft + sumRight)
  sumRight = str(i) + sumRight
sumRight = sumRight[1:]
for i in range(ch,1, -1):
  sumLeft = sumLeft[:-1]
  sumRight = sumRight[1:]
  print(" "*(ch+1-i) + sumLeft + sumRight)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Простое решение в две строки:

```py
n = int(input())
print('\n'.join(' '*abs(n-i-1)+''.join([str(min(j+1, min(n*2-i-1, i+1)*2-j-1)) 
    for j in range(2*(n-abs(n-i-1))-1)]) for i in range(n*2-1)))
```

Можно развернуть:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n*2-1):
    print(' '*abs(n-i-1), end='')
    for j in range(2*(n-abs(n-i-1))-1):
        print(min(j+1, min(n*2-i-1, i+1)*2-j-1), end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Верхняя часть кода совпадала с моей, а вот над нижней долго колдовал, да так и не смог ничего родить (я только начал учиться).
В итоге смог написать такой вариант (не без помощи добрых людей, конечно):

```
n = int(input())
for i in range (1, n+1):
    print (' ' * (n-i), *range(1, i+1), *range(i-1, 0, -1), sep='')
for j in range (n, 0, -1):
    print (' ' * (n-j+1), *range(1, j), *range(j-2, 0, -1), sep='')
```